# Is it good practice to make system root unable to be accessed?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Let's say we have the following schema:

```
root/
    application/
        -public/
            index.php
            css/
            img/
            javascript/
        ...
    system/
        ...
```

I was thinking that if I create an .htaccess file in the root with the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js|ico)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ application/public/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I would be able to make other folder except public unable to be accessed. Assume index.php is the file that load all the file the application need and include and require them (with relative paths obliviously): the application is actually run in index.php and every public file such as css stylesheet, images or javascript script are in the public folder. So you, as user, cannot access the system folder because if you digit www.site.com/ it refers to root/application/public/. Am I right?

But the htaccess rule I set there does not work... If I put that htaccess in the root folder and I try to access the root folder the browser shows me the list of the file of the root folder (application and system). Why isn't it working?

I used this while ago when index.php was in the root folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js|ico)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and it worked just fine. Why isn't the new one working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial code was right. Except for the third line which obliviously considered / a folder and made me see it instead of redirecting to application/public/.
Commenting the third line everything worked fine.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js|ico)$ - [L]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ application/public/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: You still shouldn't be doing this through .htaccess. It gets reloaded on every single request. You should be placing these directives in the virtual host definition.

Comment: @meagar how? where? Does this damage someone the application or just slow it down?

Comment: It is slow, and relies on .htaccess being enabled.

Comment: @meagar, how do I place this directive in the virtual host?

Comment: Beyond the scope of these comments. Ask a new question.

Answer (score 4):

The document root of you project should be set to the `/public` folder.

This way that's the only folder to web-user would have access to.

Edit: for more info check the apache manual http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#documentroot

Comment: if I add previously or after "DocumentRoot application/public/" it returns "Server Error".

Comment: The `DocumentRoot` should be an absolute path. I.e. the full path to the public folder.

Comment: But I cannot know where the final client path to that file. I just know there will be a application/ and a application/public/ folder. Nothing else.

Comment: I'm sorry. Speaking about .htaccess really make me nervous. I've never understood that file but I really need of it. Could please write down the .htaccess file with all the condition knowing that application/public/ should be the root of the website and that index.php URI should be attached to index.php?url=(here) ...?

Comment: @Charliepiga: You cannot set the DocumentRoot from a `.htaccess` file. You have to set it up in your httpd.conf / httpd-vhosts.conf.

Comment: why couldn't a simple RewriteRule ^(.*)$ application/public/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L] work? I'm trying to develop a public framework that could be used in different websites. I'm not really sure of anything. I'm not sure other people can set up httpd.conf / httpd-vhosts.conf. And I'm sure about the absolute path to the framework root.